# How to test Spark application performances while developping in a company?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, performance-testing, scaling

The development environment and the production environment are often different in capacity (i.e. dev cluster being firmly weaker than the production cluster).

Considering the data volumetry is similar in the two environments (by generating fake data or sanitizing prod data), a rational answer would be "if it works on a smaller cluster, it should work on a larger one". But how about a Spark application, where the main goal is to take the best out of the cluster to safely and most quickly achieve the result, how can I test the optimal spark parameterd, number and size of partitions, reasonable size of broadcast variables?